# Android Studio Upgrade 3.6.1 Issues

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

I upgraded to android studio 3.6.1 this morning.

After I sync'd everything I tried to run my application and I got the message:

Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK
The APKs are invalid.

I read a message from a long time ago that worked, but can't be correct still.  It suggested that I change the applicationId in build.graddle to a two word format.  So I did just to see and oddly it worked.

The old value was my package name that was com.salinas.abuilder.

The next problem is that google maps no longer works as the applicationId is sent to google as the package name.  Now I get the message:

2020-03-02 13:59:18.627 24572-24704/com.salinas E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.

Android Application (;): XX:YY:...:ZZ;com.salinas
and even my application is now based on this applicationId.

I read another stack overflow message on how to change the certification of the map key but it won't allow a two word package name, it needs a three word name.

So, I suspect that changing the applicationId seems to work it is covering something up.  What do I need to look at to try to uncover the real problem?

Comment: Uninstall your old build from device and then Invalidate cashes and restart your android studio then Run again and let me know its working or not ?

Comment: Were you able to fix it? I updated and am also getting the error

Comment: I did fix it and I'm not positive which change caused it to be correct.  One thing I have found usefule is after each change at this level you gave to InvalidateCache and restart.

Comment: This is driving me nuts. I can't seem to find a fix for it